# how to convert from NPVariant* to char*?

Tags: npapi

I have NPAPI plugin method which recieves NPVariant* I need to convert it to char*, I heard NPVariant does not end with NULL character so before I process the argument I need to convert it to char* , can anyone plz tell me how to convert it to char*?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I think you mean "convert it to a C-style string", not "convert it to a char*". char* is just a type, and doesn't say anything about whether or not the thing it points to is a NULL-terminated string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript and Scriptable NPAPI plugin string data on Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940692/javascript-and-scriptable-npapi-plugin-string-data-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

An NPVariant has a `type` and `value`, the value has a `stringValue` which contains a pointer UTF8Characters and UTF8Length, so it tells you the length as well.

For example:

```c
NPVariant yourVariant; //Pretend this is initialized
if (yourVariant.type == NPVariantType_String) {
    const NPUTF8* characters = yourVariant.value.stringValue.UTF8Characters;
    int length = yourVariant.value.stringValue.UTF8Length;
}
```

UTF8Characters is a NPUTF8, which may be a typedef to a char.

Knowing the length, you can construct your own char* that is null terminated.

Comment: But beware that typedefing to a char* won't make it safe to pass to functions that have a char* argument that expects a NULL-terminated string.

Comment: @smorgan Thanks man... will check that condition before processing